# If statement in R without using ifelse

Tags: r, if-statement, printing

So I am trying to use an if then statement in R or an if then print.

`if (Futures$Edge =="NONE") {Futures$Accuracy3->"NA"}`

I want to make the `accuracy3` NA if the edge is NONE, but after a lot of searching online I can't find one solution that doesn't insist on using ifelse.
 I do not want to use ifelse because I have another if else previously that would be negated.

the full code is

```
Futures$Accuracy3<- ifelse((Futures$Edge =="EDGE") & (Futures$Guess2 == Futures$Result) , 1, 0) if (Futures$Edge =="NONE") {Futures$Accuracy3->"NA"}
```

I continue to get the error message

> Warning message: In if (Futures$Edge == "NONE") { :   the condition
>   has length > 1 and only the first element will be used

here is a screenshot of the data.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4qZPr.png)

I do not want any of the NONE edges to print a 0 or 1, simply NA. Not trying to use mutate.

Comment: It should be helpful to have your full (the helpful part) code and your data or some fake data to copy and paste in R, to help you. Without them, it's quite hard to detect errors and correct them.

Comment: Do you want that if Edge==NONE, then Accuracy3==NA?

Comment: Yes, exactly that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about:

```
#fake data    Futures<-data.frame(Edge=c('NONE','EDGE','EDGE','EDGE','EDGE','NONE','EDGE','NONE','EDGE')
                       ,Accuracy3=c(0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,1))

#replace the column Accuracy3 with the ifelse    
Futures$Accuracy3 <- ifelse(Futures$Edge=='NONE', NA, Futures$Accuracy3)
> Futures
  Edge Accuracy3
1 NONE        NA
2 EDGE         0
3 EDGE         1
4 EDGE         1
5 EDGE         0
6 NONE        NA
7 EDGE         1
8 NONE        NA
9 EDGE         1
```

Comment: Eureka! Thank you.

Comment: Glad it worked! @ArianModarres if this or any answer has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.